# Help with event filters

Tags: nft, erc-721, events, erc-1155

I have been using a combination of eth_newFilter and eth_getFilterChanges for getting new NFTs minted on Ethereum and Polygon. But I miss some NFTs whenever my server gets overloaded. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QuickAlerts](https://www.quicknode.com/quickalerts), an on-chain alerting tool; using that, you can set up an alert whenever a new NFT is minted.

You won't have to manage the filters; just set up the alert and that's it. Even if your server gets overloaded, QuickAlerts has built-in retry logic, so it'll send the alerts when your server is healthy again.

Use the following expression in QuickAlerts:

```
((tx_logs_topic0 == '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef' && tx_logs_topic1 == '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' && tx_logs_topic3_int > 0)||(tx_logs_topic0 == '0xc3d58168c5ae7397731d063d5bbf3d657854427343f4c083240f7aacaa2d0f62' && tx_logs_topic2 == '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')||(tx_logs_topic0 == '0x4a39dc06d4c0dbc64b70af90fd698a233a518aa5d07e595d983b8c0526c8f7fb' && tx_logs_topic2 == '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'))
```

Let's understand the above example; every smart contract event has log fields containing information about the type of event emitted and parameters used to execute the smart contract function, which then emits an event.

For an NFT Transfer event

- `tx_logs_topic0` contains the name of the event being emitted.
- `tx_logs_topic1` contains the sender address.
- `tx_logs_topic2` contains the receiver address.
- `tx_logs_topic3` contains the token id.

In our example, we are using 3 `tx_logs_topic0` to target three types of NFT transfer events.

- *Transfer*: 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
- *TransferSingle*: 0xc3d58168c5ae7397731d063d5bbf3d657854427343f4c083240f7aacaa2d0f62
- *TransferBatch*: 0x4a39dc06d4c0dbc64b70af90fd698a233a518aa5d07e595d983b8c0526c8f7fb

For `tx_logs_topic2`, we are just mentioning empty addresses with 0s as we just want to target mints, and for `tx_logs_topic3`, we are saying that any token with a token id more than 0.

Some more resources around QuickAlerts:

- Docs: https://www.quicknode.com/quickalerts
- Video: https://youtu.be/Y3UZDxX-ZD8
- Written Guide: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/quicknode-products/quickalerts/an-overview-of-quicknodes-quickalerts
- Written Guide: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/quicknode-products/quickalerts/tracking-blockchain-event-data-with-quicknodes-quickalerts-expressions